# How do I check whether a function which uses a promise was successful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have these two functions. What I want when I call foo, then check whether it succeeded. So currently I'm doing something as suggested in this answer: [Returning a value from a function depending on whether a Promise was resolved or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259598/returning-a-value-from-a-function-depending-on-whether-a-promise-was-resolved-or)

```
function foo() {
  performOp()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('it worked!');
      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('it failed!');
      return false;
    });
}

function bar() {
  foo().then(val => console.log(val));
}
```

The thinking here is that foo will return a promise to bar, and bar will print the result. Instead, what I'm seeing is that the return value of foo() is undefined.

Comment: You do not return anything in foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because you are not returning anything, otherwise the function returns `undefined` by default. Given that `performOp` is a `promise` it will be:

```
function foo() {
  return performOp()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('it worked!');
      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('it failed!');
      return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is using promises in this way considered good practice?

Comment: It's not about good practice or bad. You have to return the promise from the function if you want to use it to chain promises. the `return true` or `return false` is the return value for that particular then/catch callback. And this kind of promise chaining is pretty common. for ref you can check out `async/await` which is mostly syntactic sugar but the syntax is easier. :)